# Get constants of Model

Tags: php, cakephp

**CakePHP:** 2.3.5

```
class Table extends AppModel {

    const STATUS_FREE = 0;
    const STATUS_BUSY = 1;
    const STATUS_INCHECK = 2;
    const STATUS_LINK = 3;
    const STATUS_CLEAN = 4;
    const STATUS_CASHIER = 9;
```

I'm in **TablesController**, and I need access this constants.
The only way I founded for do that, is:

```
$this->loadModel('Table');
$free = Table::STATUS_FREE;
```

I try too:

```
self::STATUS_FREE
```

Why I need use `$this->loadModel`, if I in TablesController?

Comment: Is `TablesController` != `Table`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: TablesController != Table, because Table is a Model (app/Model/Table.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need loadModel. You just need the class included.
You can also achieve that via App::uses() - which kind of works as a lazy loaded require().

Just include the classes you need the constants from above your main class. Always.

```
App::uses('Table', 'Model');
App::uses('OtherModelWithContantsYouNeed', 'Model');

class TablesController extends AppController {}
```

Now you can use your constants anywhere in your controller code as well as all its views!

This is also how I do it for my class constants in my enums ( http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/ ).
There is also explained in more detail what is going on.

Comment: I thought this was already default in order that Table is Model of TablesController. Anyway, thanks mark!

Comment: It is usually. But this will be decided too late at runtime. The static access happens prior to the auto-inclusion. Thats why this manual definition needs to be - but it also doesnt hurt :)